# WithNewWindow() returns MultipleCompilationErrorsException in Geb

Tags: grails, groovy, closures, functional-testing, geb

I am getting weird error in my geb functional tests.

```
 org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Spec expression: 1: expecting '}', found 'assert' @ line 1, column 71.
    } ) { at(JobOfferDetailPage) assert des
```

My test looks like this. I click on a link which opens a new window with details of the job offer. Than I want to assert some text on the new page using Page Pattern.

Test:

```
withNewWindow( { quickShowOption.click() } ) { //TODO fix me
                    at(JobOfferDetailPage)
                    assert description.text() == 'some text'
                    assert requirements.text() == 'some text'
                    assert advatages.text() == 'some text.'
                    assert categories.text() == 'some text'
                    assert locality.text() == 'some text'
                }
```

Page:

```
class JobOfferDetailPage extends Page {
    static at = {$('#contactLabel').text() == 'Contact'}

    static content = {
        description {$('#jobOfferDescription')}
        requirements {$('#jobOfferRequirements')}
        advatages {$('#jobOfferAdvantages')}
        jobOfferType {$('#jobOfferType')}
        categories {$('#categories')}
        locality {$('#locality')}
        startDate {$('#startDate')}
        requiredLanguages {$('#requiredLanguages')}
    }
}
```

I get compilation error after my conditions are asserted. If I make a typo in asserted text than the test will fail normally, but if it passes, than it fails with this weird error.

---

Thank you @Erdi.

I use spock,geb versions "0.13.1" and selenium version "2.51.0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one was to believe [this comment in one of Geb's own tests](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/57081c8a8c8694a9a72ca194982d88bcff1a116f/module/geb-core/src/test/groovy/geb/window/WindowHandlingSpec.groovy#L232), which was nota bene written by me some time ago, this indeed seems like some sort of bug in Spock. What is interesting is that I just now moved that statement to an expect block and it works as long as the last statement in the second closure passed to `newWindow()` evaluates to true. This makes me think that it is an issue with old version of Spock and/or Groovy. Which versions of the aforementioned tools are you using?

One possible workaround would be to move your statement from `expect`/`then` to one that is not asserting (`given` or `when`) as shown in the test I linked to.